# Доступ к вложенному пространству имен в C#

Tags: c#, namespace

В начале программы у меня стоит `using System;`.

И внутри программы, в методе `Main()` хочу обратиться к пространству имен `Diagnostics`, вложенному в `System`, но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к нему, получаю ошибку, что такого пространства не существует...

И получается, что я могу к нему обратиться только, когда прописано полное квалифицированное имя (`System.Diagnostics`) или же когда прописан дополнительный `using System.Diagnostics;`.

Могу ли я как-то обратиться к классу в пространстве имен `System.Diagnostics`, прописав в начале программы просто `using System;`?

Comment: А что вам мешает прописать `using System.Diagnostics;` и использовать дальше спокойно его возможности, а не делать себе проблемы на пустом месте?

Comment: У меня уже существует класс с таким же именем, как и в ```System.Diagnostics```, поэтому не могу...

Comment: Ну значит пропишите конкретно какой вам класс нужен и из какого он `Namespace` (например `using Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug;`), а еще лучше, не называйте классы так, как они называются в фреймворке. Ну и `Diagnostics` нужен только для отладки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию!